# C++ Error C2661: no overloaded function takes x arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, struct

I'm trying to create a class that contains structs of the following types:

```
 struct gameObject
       {
         int row;                       // row position of the object
         int column;                    // column position of the object
         bool isFound;          // flag to indicate if the object has been found (or is dead, in the case of the monster)
         bool isVisible;        // flag to indicate if the object can be seen on the board -add in week 4
        };

struct playerObject
{
    bool alive;             // flag to indicate if the player is alive or dead
    bool hasWeapon;         // flag to indicate if the player has the weapon
    bool hasTreasure;       // flag to indicate if the player has the treasure
    bool hasTorch;          // flag to indicate if the player has the torch -add in week 4
    bool hasNoisemaker;     // flag to indicate if the player has the noisemaker -add in week 4
    bool hasKey;
    gameObject position;    // variables for row, column and visibility
};
```

I'm doing this so I can have all of my "game pieces" and their data under one object to hopefully help with readability.
The class I'm trying to declare is below:

```
class pieces{//the class for the game and player objects
public:
    pieces();
    ~pieces();
    gameObjectType hold = EMPTY;                         // Holds objects under the monster<bug fix>
    // </WK6>
    playerObject player = { true, false, false, false, false, false, { -1, -1, false, true } };  // the player
    gameObject treasure ={ -1, -1, false, true };           // the treasure
    gameObject monster = { -1, -1, false, true };           // the monster
    gameObject weapon = { -1, -1, false, true };            // the weapon
    gameObject torch = { -1, -1, false, true };             // the torch
    gameObject noisemaker = { -1, -1, false, true };  // the noisemaker
    gameObject key = { -1, -1, false, true };
    gameObject caveExit = { -1, -1, false, true };          // the cave exit

};
```

The problem is that I keep getting a C2661 error. For all of my gameObject declarations it says `error C2661: 'gameObject::gameObject' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments`
However, for my playerObject, it says the same except with 7 arguments instead of 4.

I've been at it for hours and I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: What version of VS is this?

Comment: It's version 2013.

Comment: The syntax you're trying to use (qualified list initialization for non-static data members) doesn't work on MSVC2013 due to a [compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792161/constructor-initializer-list-does-not-support-braced-init-list-form). However, VS2013 update 3 should have fixed it - do you have the most recent updates to your Visual Studio install?

Comment: I thought I did, but let me double check.

Comment: I'm gonna try updating to update 5 and see if it helps

Comment: it worked for me in Visual studio 2015 apart from fact that I need to comment gameObjectType as it is not given by you.

Answer (score -1):

If you declare you structs like this:

```
typedef struct gameObject {
   {
     int row;                       // row position of the object
     int column;                    // column position of the object
     bool isFound;          // flag to indicate if the object has been found (or is dead, in the case of the monster)
     bool isVisible;        // flag to indicate if the object can be seen on the board -add in week 4
    } gameObject;
```

Then I expect it will all work. Note the gameObject after the '}'

Comment: Interestingly in VS2013 I get this when I run your code: error C2797: 'pieces::player': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented

Comment: seems @birryee is correct: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/somasegar/2013/06/28/c-conformance-roadmap/

Comment: This is C++, not C. Nobody would write such code in C++ except maybe if he share some code between C and C++.

Comment: I'm still learning c++, so my understanding of it is shaky at best. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @KarlaBarraza [In C, user-defined type names are put in the "tag" name space, and need to be preceded by `struct`/`enum`/`union`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612350#612350); you have to explicitly `typedef` the type if you want to use it as is.  For example, in your code, you would have to use `struct gameObject` to declare a `gameObject`, instead of just `gameObject`.  `typedef struct X X;`, as shown here, lets you use the name by itself, as `gameObject`.  ...In C++, this is unnecessary, and "tag names" are available as is.

Comment: @PaulColdrey The issue appears to be that the compiler has trouble with default member initialisers, when the member being initialised is of a user-defined type.  Providing the name as a `typedef` wouldn't solve it; if it _does_, that means it's probably time to get a new compiler.

Comment: @Justin Time - Agreed as per my later comment. Also, sadly, the reality is he does need a new compiler because it is a failing of VS 2013.On reflection I agree this is not very C++-like but the reality is that his code is correct and the compiler is crap so it was not that unlikely that this more prescriptive (old-school) syntax might have solved his problems.